# How to go back to "repeat" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, repeat

Is it possible to go back to a `repeat` in Prolog without calling the predicate and without making a new predicate?

I have the following code

```
test :- nl,
write('Welcome.'),nl,
repeat, write('Print this message again? (yes/no)'),nl,
read(Ans),nl,
(
    Ans == yes -> write('You selected yes.'), nl
;
    write('You selected no.')
).
```

The current output I get is

```
Welcome.
Print this message again? (yes/no)
yes.
You selected yes.
true.
```

Program end.

The output I want is

```
Welcome.
Print this message again? (yes/no)
yes.
You selected yes.
Print this message again? (yes/no)
no.
```

Program ends.

The easy output way I want to avoid (I don't want this output. I don't want it shows Welcome multiple of times):

```
Welcome.
Print this message again? (yes/no)
yes.

Welcome.
You selected yes.
Print this message again? (yes/no)
no.
```

Program ends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Repeat

`repeat/0` is [simply defined as](http://eclipseclp.org/docs/current/bips/kernel/control/repeat-0.html):

```
repeat.
repeat :- repeat.
```

Or, equivalently:

```
repeat :- true ; repeat.
```

In order to repeat, you need to backtrack up to the `repeat` call by failing, either explicitely with `fail` or through another failing predicate (see example in the above link).

```
...
repeat,
...,
fail.
```

Once you want to exit the repeating pattern, you can (and should) cut `!` the decision tree so that you don't have a dangling `repeat` choice point.
If you don't, the interpreter will still have the possibility to backtrack to `repeat` later.

NB: the rules for `!/0` can be [found here](http://eclipseclp.org/docs/current/bips/kernel/control/I-0.html).

## Example

For you example specifically, that means (btw, I use `writeln`):

```
test :- 
  nl,
  writeln('Welcome.'),
  repeat, 
  writeln('Print this message again? (yes/no)'),
  read(Ans),nl,
  (Ans == yes -> 
    writeln('You selected yes.'), 
    fail % backtrack to repeat
  ; writeln('You selected no.'),
    ! % cut, we won't backtrack to repeat anymore
  ).
```

## Other remarks

Notice that OP used atoms, whereas strings are sufficient. 
Indeed, atoms (single-quotes) are hashed and prefered for symbolic reasoning, whereas strings (double-quotes) are not interned and are more adequate for displaying messages.

In the same spirit, when reading, I'd rather use  `read_string(end_of_line,_,S)`, which reads up-to the end of line and returns a string. With `read/1`, I had to close the input stream with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, which was annoying.

Also, we can get rid of `->` completely:

```
test :- 
  nl,
  writeln("Welcome."),
  repeat, 
  writeln("Print this message again? (yes/no)"),
  read_string(end_of_line,_,Ans),
  nl,
  write("You selected "),
  write(Ans),
  writeln("."),
  Ans == "no", % Otherwise, repeat
  !.
```

Removing `->` might be controversial seeing how other people argue about having more cases. Here is the rationale: since the original question seems to be an homework about `repeat`, the parts about handling `yes`, `no` and bad inputs explicitely seems to be underspecified, and frankly, not really relevant. I kept the original semantics and merged the `yes` and bad-input cases: after all, what happens when user says `yes`? we repeat, exactly as when a user types an unexpected input. The only case where we do not `repeat` is when `Ans == no`.

Now, if we want to change the behavior of the original code in order to explicitely check for all possible kind of inputs, here is an attempt:

```
test :- 
  nl,
  writeln("Welcome."),
  repeat, 
  writeln("Print this message again? (yes/no)"),
  read_string(end_of_line,_,Ans),
  nl,
  (memberchk(Ans,["yes","no"]) ->
    write("You selected "),
    write(Ans),
    writeln("."),
    Ans == "no",
    !
  ; writeln("Bad input" : Ans),
    fail).
```

Comment: Does the "fail" has to be before the ";" and the "!" after the ";" all the time?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you negate your test, then `fail` and `!` will be swapped, along with the different subterms. It might take a while to absorb how Prolog evaluation works. Try to `break` your program and execute it step-by-step. Use different examples, don't hesitate to experiment.

Comment: Thank you, I think I know my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't try to do:

```
test :- 
     nl, write('Welcome.'), 
     nl, test_internal.

test_internal :- 
     write('Print this message again? (yes/no)'), nl,
     read(Ans), nl,
     (    Ans == yes 
     ->   write('You selected yes.'), nl, test_internal
     ;    Ans == no, write('You selected no.'), !
     ;    test_internal
     ).
```

**EDIT**

If you cannot separate the predicate in two, another solution (use the *coredump* one's) could be:

```
test :- 
     nl, write('Welcome.'), 
     repeat, nl,
     write('Print this message again? (yes/no)'), nl,
     read(Ans), nl,
     (    Ans == yes 
     ->   write('You selected yes.'), fail
     ;    Ans == no, write('You selected no.'), !
     ;    fail
     ).
```

#### Edit: alternative using if-then and different layout

To further increase readability, `(->)/2` (if-then-ELSE-FAIL) can be used (c.f. [SWI-Prolog manual section on control predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=control)). 
Also, a different layout of the if-then-else cascade can help.

```
test :- 
     nl, write('Welcome.'), 
     repeat, nl,
     write('Print this message again? (yes/no)'), nl,
     read(Ans), nl,
     (    Ans == yes -> write('You selected yes.'), fail
     ;    Ans == no  -> write('You selected no.'),  !
     ).
```

Note that the use of if-then-ELSE-FAIL is not strictly necessary---conjunction could be used. Using it, however, makes it easy to add code handling additional cases (`maybe`, `i_dont_know`, `i_m_afraid`, `i_gotta_go`) in the future.

Comment: I'm not allow to make another new function beside "test".

Comment: @repeat: See if I change it in a more readable way, if not... feel free to add an edit field below my script. ;)

Comment: @repeat Note that the behavior originally described by OP was exactly that: everything that is not `yes` means `no` ;-) I just followed the same logic. But see my edits where I also consider more explicit checks.